# dell c6220 ACPI power soft-off

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

On a Dell C6220 server with 4 nodes it occurs from time to time that all 4 nodes are powered off.
It seems to happen when there is a slight power fluctuation (despite there being an UPS on both power supplies, in fact 2 different UPSes for the 2 PSUs).

There are 5 other servers on the same UPSes (other models, not C6220), none of which turn off at that moment.

Message in the system log is:

```
2018/01/31  12:21:10  System ACPI Power State Sys Pwr Monitor S5/G2: soft-off
```

It is impossible to turn on any of the nodes with the power button or via software. The only way to turn them back on is to remove the power cables from BOTH power supply units and plug them back in.

This is the same behaviour as described in the post [here on the Dell forum](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/poweredgec-tools/2014-November/000302.html), however, there is no answer/solution on that post.

Is there any way to avoid it? What is the reason for this behaviour? None of my other servers did turn off. Admittedly, there was a slight power problem (possibly 0.5 sec power off) but with 2 separate UPSes I would expect that at least one of them would not have forwarded the power drop to the server, even if one of them would be faulty.

There are a number of power config options on the C6220.
Here is how they are set:

```
Power Management <NodeManager>
Chassis Power Management > Chassis PSU Configuration
  Required Power Supplies: 1
  Redundant Power Supplies: 1
Power Capping
  Chassis Level Capping: Enabled
Emergency Throttling
  Sled Level Policy: Chassis Level
  Chassis Level Policy: Throttling
```

These settings are the same on all 4 nodes.

BIOS version  2.5.3 
BMC version   2.59

Comment: Sounds like you need a power conditioner.

Comment: @nepdev I'm running into this same exact issue with the Dell C6220 as well. A power event preceded the lock up of an entire cabinet of Dell C6220s -- only resolved by unplugging both PSUs on the server. My power is also UPS-backed. Did you ever find a solution for this or did you pursue a line conditioner as Davidw recommended?

Comment: Talking power conditioner - I have later installed a double-conversion online UPS (Cyberpower) which SHOULD mean zero fluctuations and zero transfer time on blackouts/brownouts. But the C6220 still has a problem. I put that UPS because I had tested it earlier - I could create that problem by taking the line power off my old UPS. But then, the new UPS did not then seem to handle it.

Comment: I noticed that when it was extremely hot in summer here, it occured a few times. Since it became colder, it never happened again. Theoretically it could be an out-of-tolerance sensor on some of these C6220s. But then again it never reports a temperature-related problem in the logs.

Comment: @nepdev Hmm, so it sounds like you're still facing the same issue? Was there anything that you've been able to do that at least reduced the occurrence of these lock up issues?

Comment: The problem did not occur in the last 3 months at all - haven't changed anything. As I said, it's colder here now - hardly more than a guess ...